# Instagram Api to send and fetch Direct messages

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Do we have Instagram-APIs which captures Direct-Messages(DMs) for an account? APIs which provide the info of DMs sent to that account and DMs received for that account. Something like webhook.

I had searched facebook developer docs and found no useful info regarding this.

Help.

Comment: if there is no info about it in the developer docs, then it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have an facebook business account and instagram business account. After that you have to link each other. Maybe you will get messages from webhook.

I ask this question to facebook direct support and i get this answer:

The instagram_manage_insights permission allows your app to get access to insights for the Instagram account linked to a Facebook Page. Your app can also discover and read the profile info and media of other business profiles. The allowed usage for this permission is to get metadata, data insights and story insights of an Instagram Business account. You may also use this permission to request analytics insights to improve your app and for marketing or advertising purposes, through the use of aggregated and de-identified or anonymized information (provided such data cannot be re-identified).

Allowed Usages

Get metadata of an Instagram Business account.
Get data insights of an Instagram Business account.
Get story insights of an Instagram Business account.

For more information please access [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/instagram_manage_insights/) link.